# Qt's mouseMoveEvent is too slow

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I want to implement a Paint-like widget, where you can draw figures with your mouse.

But the `mouseMoveEvent` isn't called frequently engough to do that: If you want to draw a line and you go average fast with your mouse, then you will end up with a kind of dotted line..

Is there any setting in Qt that adjusts this behaviour? Is there any (platform independent) alternative way to get an event when moving the mouse (while using Qt for the window)?

Comment: have you checked with this example? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html

Comment: Your assumptions about `mouseMoveEvent` are wrong. It is not guaranteed to report events as triggered by the hardware. Instead, the system (every system I know of anyway) coalesces several hardware events into a single logical `mouseMoveEvent`, that represents the relative movement from the last time you checked. I don't know of a platform independent solution (on Windows you could use [GetMouseMovePointsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646259.aspx)). A platform independent solution probably involves drawing lines (instead of dots).

Comment: @Hayt I searched for such a example and I didn't find one. Thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable I doubt that this approximation will work because the holes are pretty big. But i'll have a try.

Comment: @andrew: *"I doubt that this approximation will work because the holes are pretty big"* - Well, then, you won't have much fun with the [Scribble Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) either. It uses exactly that approximation. It's either that, or platform-dependent mouse input handling.

Comment: @IInspectable So how does this work? Is `mouseMoveEvent` certainly triggered if there is a change in direction? Because otherwise this approximation wouldn't work.

Comment: `mouseMoveEvent` is subject to the implementation details of the specific platform the application runs on. I can only comment on Windows' implementation, and there is certainly no guarantee that you get notified of the extrema when changing directions. You only get native `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages if the message queue is empty and the mouse has moved since the last time you called a message retrieval function. Since Qt abuses the message queue, by dumping loads of unnecessary messages, the adverse effects are more noticeable with Qt applications than with native applications.

Comment: `GetMouseMovePointsEx` can be used to remedy the artifacts, but I believe Qt is way too destructive with respect to native Windows messages for that to produce reliable results (for example, it assigns new time stamps for `mouseMoveEvent`s instead of retaining the native time stamps). In short, if you need that kind of high precision input handling, you will have to write platform-specific code. For a reliable result, you'll likely have to dump Qt altogether, as it unrecoverably interferes with native input handling.

Comment: Using [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) works great. Thanks.

Comment: There is no advantage in implementing do-it-yourself line drawing to using `QPainter`'s `drawLine`. And neither one addresses the issue you are trying to solve: Getting accurate mouse movement information. Whether you perform manual rendering using any given algorithm, or the built-in line drawing code, there is no guarantee that you will get events for the turning points when changing direction, for example. Likewise, drawing quick circles will not give you well rounded shapes, no matter how you perform your line drawing.